# How to use Text qualifier to read delimited file in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to read a file containing data like :

```
"Name","Surname","Age","Birthdate","Address","PhoneNumber"
"Chaitra","Shenoy","21","1995-08-26","A-123,Spring blossom Area"
"Sapna","Soni","22","1994-04-16","B-56,Ganga Park,Ghorpadi","9022"
"Tanvi","Mutha","48","1969-03-24","A-23,Valencia,Mundhwa","1256","Yes"
"Shivani","Adsar","55","1961-11-09","Saptami-234,Udita,Salt Lake","5485"
"Chaitra","Shenoy","21","1995-08-26","A-123,Spring blossom Area","5555"
"Sapna","Soni","22","1994-04-16","B-56,Ganga Park,Ghorpadi"
```

Here while using `spark.read.option(delimiter,",").csv(filename)` to read the file I can properly read the column Address properly even though it contains ',' which is the delimiter.
But the problem with this approach is that it for rows that contains extra or less number of columns the read function truncates or appends extra delimiter respectively in the data frame created. This is not the desired output.

My desired output would be the rows which contain required number of delimiters which is 5 in this case. Records with more or less delimiters need to be rejected.

So the good records would be :

```
"Sapna","Soni","22","1994-04-16","B-56,Ganga Park,Ghorpadi","9022"
"Shivani","Adsar","55","1961-11-09","Saptami-234,Udita,Salt Lake","5485"
"Chaitra","Shenoy","21","1995-08-26","A-123,Spring blossom Area","5555"
```

And my bad records would be:

```
"Chaitra","Shenoy","21","1995-08-26","A-123,Spring blossom Area"
"Tanvi","Mutha","48","1969-03-24","A-23,Valencia,Mundhwa","1256","Yes"
"Sapna","Soni","22","1994-04-16","B-56,Ganga Park,Ghorpadi"
```

Reading the file as mentioned above doesn't let me recognize bad records.

How can this be done?

Comment: "This is not the desired output" - and what _is_ the desired output? A DataFrame necessarily contains a common schema for _all_ records, it can't contain less columns for some records.

Comment: @TzachZohar Have updated my question with all details.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data

```
"Name","Surname","Age","Birthdate","Address","PhoneNumber"
"Chaitra","Shenoy","21","1995-08-26","A-123,Spring blossom Area"
"Sapna","Soni","22","1994-04-16","B-56,Ganga Park,Ghorpadi","9022"
"Tanvi","Mutha","48","1969-03-24","A-23,Valencia,Mundhwa","1256","Yes"
"Shivani","Adsar","55","1961-11-09","Saptami-234,Udita,Salt Lake","5485"
"Chaitra","Shenoy","21","1995-08-26","A-123,Spring blossom Area","5555"
"Sapna","Soni","22","1994-04-16","B-56,Ganga Park,Ghorpadi"
```

It seems that there is a header which can be used for column names in your dataframe. You can use header option and format option as below

```
spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .csv("path to your csv file")
  .show(false)
```

This should give you output dataframe as

```
+-------+-------+---+----------+---------------------------+-----------+
|Name   |Surname|Age|Birthdate |Address                    |PhoneNumber|
+-------+-------+---+----------+---------------------------+-----------+
|Chaitra|Shenoy |21 |1995-08-26|A-123,Spring blossom Area  |null       |
|Sapna  |Soni   |22 |1994-04-16|B-56,Ganga Park,Ghorpadi   |9022       |
|Tanvi  |Mutha  |48 |1969-03-24|A-23,Valencia,Mundhwa      |1256       |
|Shivani|Adsar  |55 |1961-11-09|Saptami-234,Udita,Salt Lake|5485       |
|Chaitra|Shenoy |21 |1995-08-26|A-123,Spring blossom Area  |5555       |
|Sapna  |Soni   |22 |1994-04-16|B-56,Ganga Park,Ghorpadi   |null       |
+-------+-------+---+----------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

I hope the answer helps

Comment: But when I write this dataframe as a file, delimiters are appended or truncated and bad records cannot be recognized.